# How to keep bugs away?

Tags: beer, cider

I'm making cider and I dont have the space to brew inside so I'm brewing outside.  It draws a lot of attention from bugs, particularly yellow jackets.  I have it in a sealed container, so there's no risk of contamination from bugs or bacteria.

I dont want to get stung when I check on my brew, there are always at least 20 yellow jackets around my brew.  I tried moving it multiple times, but they always manage to find it.  Has anybody else experienced this problem?  How would I go about stopping the yellow jackets from swarming around the brew?

Comment: Consider brewing smoked beers :p

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered an ultraviolet electric wasp killer like these: http://amzn.com/B00JER3I22 (just an example... Not pushing that model in particular)  - No chemicals, just a bit of electricity... Set them up and the wasps are attracted to the UV light, before getting electrocuted, and will bother you no more - It's what they use in professional kitchens to keep bugs at bay!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.  I sprayed insecticide around the bucket that I am brewing in.  It seems to have deterred the yellow jackets from swarming around my brew.  I was hoping for a natural solution as I don't like harming the grass

Answer (score 0):

I've used cinnamon powder to repel wasps from my balcony and it worked. You could also try this. Since your bucket is outside, you'll probably need to apply it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ wasp traps - rather than try to deter the wasps, just catch them. In theory, it will reduce the number because those trapped cannot return to the nest and tell their friends.

However the wasps *might* find your cider more attractive than the contents of the traps. Although if so, use some of your cider *as* bait.